# Register Task scheduler from windows service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

Register Task scheduler from windows service but its not working.

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
```

Code written inside the Service

```
public static void RegisterTask()
{
    using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
    {
            TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
            td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Windows Service";

            td.Settings.AllowDemandStart = false;
            td.Settings.StartWhenAvailable = true;
            td.Settings.RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable = true;

            var trigger = new TimeTrigger();
            trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            td.Triggers.Add(trigger);

            string exePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "svhostservice.exe");
            td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(exePath, "Service", null));
            ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Windows Service", td);

    }
}
```

Is windows service unable to register Task scheduler? It's working perfectly when I use this code inside EXE (WPF application)

Comment: Well, completely empty `catch` blocks aren't going to help you in tracking down the problem.

Comment: yes but its not working in  windows service  any idea?